# program compiles but won't run in command box

Tags: java, windows, editplus

every time while i try to run java program in command prompt, it shows "could not find or load the main class.

```
class A 
{
    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");
    }
}
```

javac -d ../classes A.java
compiles successfully

then try to run in classes folder

java A

i got the message
"couldn't find or load main class A"

Comment: That shouldn't be required. `echo 'class a{public static void main(String[]_){System.exit(42);}}'>a.java&& javac a.java&&java a;echo $?`. `42`

Comment: Is that the entire file? Just in case, if you have a `package foo` statement at the top you need `java foo.A` instead.

Comment: my all programs gives the same message. i could ran these programs while ago without the classpath

Comment: @shahim more than likely you were not outputting the class files to the `classes` folder

Comment: @Vlad yes. no package

Answer (score 3):

Add the `classes` folder to the classpath

```
java -cp ../classes A
```

Comment: OP says they are in the "classes" folder.  You don't need to add the current folder to the class path.  This answer won't make the slightest bit of difference.  -1.

Comment: need it to apply for every programs? my all programs gives the same message. i could ran these programs while ago without the classpath

Comment: Yes, if you want to run the application in a directory other than the `classes` folder

Comment: @DavidWallace yes it will make a difference in the 1st scenario where the `OP` is not located in the `classes` folder

Comment: but i telling that i could run these programs in the same way what i did. but now i can't.

Comment: As I said above, you were probably dumping the classes into the same location as the source files, now they are in the `classes` folder so you need to add this to the classpath

Answer (score 0):

You are compiling with `-d` option .So package structure will be created .If your class is packaged then you have to use fully quallified class name means `outerpackage.innerpackge.A`